# zsh : Removing run of certain characters at the end of a variable

Tags: zsh

To keep it simple, consider following task:

*Given a non-empty shell variable `var`, where we know that the last character is the letter `a` and that at least one character is not an `a`, remove all the `a` from the right of the variable.*

Example: If the variable initially contains *abcadeaaa*, it should contain *abcade* afterwards.

I wondering whether this can be done in a compact way in Zsh.

Of course this is trivial to do using an external program (such as `sed`), or by using a *while* loop, where we consecutively strip the last `a` (`${VAR%a}`), until the value of the variable doesn't change anymore. Both would work in a POSIX shell, in bash or in ksh. However, given that Zsh has so many nice features for expansion, I wonder, whether there isn't a better way.

The problem is that matching a run of a certain character (independend of length) cries out for regular expressions, but the pattern after `%` in parameter expansion, and the pattern in the `s///` substitution, both is a wildcard pattern, which doesn't allow me to do what I want - at least according to my understanding of the *zshexpn* man page.

Any ideas for this?

Note that this question is not to solve a real-world problem (in which case I simply would use `sed` to do the job, as this would get the job done), but more out of academic interest, to find out how far we can stretch the limits of the Zsh expansion mechanism.

Comment: You need to `setopt extendedglob`, then `${VAR%a##}` will work. (`##` is the equivalent of regexp's `+`)

Comment: Ah, I missed this one. BTW, the correct expression would then be `${VAR%%a##}`, not `${VAR%a##}`. A single `%`-sign would still remove only one *a* from the end, because it tries the shortest match. It is a pity that I have to use *extendedglob* for this. I don't like this feature, because I always need to remember to set it back afterwards. It would be handy if I could turn on *extendedglob* just for one pattern, by some magic switch in the globbing flags....

Comment: I'm not aware of a shorter way. However you could use `setopt localoptions extendedglob` to disable it at end of function.

Comment: You can also use `setopt kshglob`, then `${VAR%%+(a)}`. It has the same issue as `extendedglob`, but perhaps you wouldn't mind leaving that enabled,